# Looking for a word to describe when something happens and it is not caused by someone or some thing

Tags: single-word-requests

The belief that some things just happen. No one is at fault and there is no cause. Kind of like what I’ve heard described as “an act of God” but I don’t care for that phrase. Is there a word for this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean fate or destiny? Try reading about Greek tragedy.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: In legal texts, an "act of God" is often used as a hyponym (a sub-category) of [_force majeure_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_majeure).

Comment: It something is an act of God, how can it "just happen"? Beyond the legal meaning of force majeure.

Comment: @Lambie I'm afraid that if I board your train of thought, it will take me out of linguistic territory and into philosophy... I'm staying on my platform for now...

Comment: @m.a.a.  I like that about boarding a train of thought. :)

Comment: We're in King's Cross, you say? I think if you so desired, you'd be able to board a train.

Comment: Thank you all! Wow, what a great site

Answer (score 2):

A single word could be **chance**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chance) has

> **chance**
> **1 a**: something that happens unpredictably without discernible human intention or observable cause
> **1 b**: the assumed impersonal purposeless determiner of unaccountable happenings
> **1 c**: the fortuitous or incalculable element in existence

For example

> I was saved from drowning at sea by a **chance** encounter with a fishing boat.

Answer (score 0):

Weather Vane has provided a solid suggestion.

Judging from the opening line of you query, though, it might be that you're looking for a word that connotes *"the belief that some things just happen"*, i.e. the *belief* in chance.

If this is the case, I reckon [accidentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidentalism_(philosophy)) is a nice alternative:

> In philosophy, accidentalism denies the causal closure of physical
> determinism and maintains that events can succeed one another
> haphazardly or by chance (not in the mathematical but in the popular
> sense).